# I want to create an html hyperlink by concating one of the variables from postgresql

Tags: html, concatenation

I am new to html
I have values returned from postgresql in my html which i display in a table. I want to generate a relative hyperlink. How to do it. For eg the value of todo[3]= "UX123456" and my website is [www.dispatchmonitor.com](http://www.dispatchmonitor.com). I want to generate a hyperlink [www.dispatchmonitor.com/logfiles/UX123456](http://www.dispatchmonitor.com/logfiles/UX123456)
Please tell me how to achieve the desired result

```
  {% for todo in todos %}
            <tr style="font-size:13px;height:30px">
                <td style="text-align:center">{{ todo[0] }}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center">{{ todo[1]}}</td>
                 ...
                  ...
              **<td style="text-align:center"> <a href='./logfiles/{todo[3]}'>log</a></td>**
               ....
               ...
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Typo: The whole  URL has to go **inside** the quotes around the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: Also you can't link to `file:` URLs from `http:` URLs for security reasons (and I assume that your template code is being processed with server-side programming).

Comment: Yes it will be on server, but right now everything is hosted on my computer Eventually the file url will be gone and replaced by the server url, Right now everything is hosted on my computer and I am trying to access the files locally

Comment: When I said "can't" I meant "can't". The link will be blocked by the browser for security reasons.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are using a templating language, this is not plain HTML.

But you can try to use template litterals : just put backticks `` (`) `` around your string and then embed your data like this `${variable}`

Documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: No. That template language definitely is not using JS Template Literal syntax.

Comment: NO I am using plain html, this html template is being used from flask I tried the $variable it did not work